# How to remove login page SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, login-page

i'm working on a project an my task is removing sugar login page to make website looks like it can be access by everyone. I'm using SugarCE-6.5.11. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an SSO type of solution? Sugar supports both SAML and LDAP natively, so you should be able to authenticate via those and not have the traditional login screen.

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/05_Sugar_Community_Edition/Sugar_Community_Edition_6.4/Sugar_Community_Edition_Administration_Guide_6.4.0/03_Users#LDAP_Support

Alternatively, you could do something similar to what we do for the Free Trial environment and override the login screen to embed the logins into buttons on the screen, passing the username/password in the request.